# Delphi: access properties of Field variable directly

Tags: delphi, properties

i have a class which contains another class.
Is it possible in Delphi to directly access the properties of the member class?

```
TNameValue = class
private
  FSubName: string;
  FSubValue: Integer;
public
  property SubName: string read FSubName write FSubName;
  property SubValue: Integer read FSubValue write FSubValue;
end;

TParentclass = class(TSomeotherclass)
  FNameValue: TNameValue;
public
  property NameValue: TNameValue read FNameValue write FNameValue;
end;

procedure TForm.Buttonclick();
begin
  Parentclass := TParentclass.Create();
  // here i would need to directly access the Property of the member class.
  Showmessage(Parentclass.Subname);
end;
```

I know that i could make properties for alle the properties of the subclass that i want to access, but i have this class in multiple other classes and i don't want to change the code everywhere when the subclass changes.

Is there a way to define the property to publish its properties directly?
I know that i can access it using Parentclass.NameValue.Subname but i want to use it without the additional step of NameValue.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you correctly - you seem to be mixing the terms fields and properties, but on the face of it you need to make the relevant fields/properties of the subclass protected.

Comment: That's not a subclass. That term is used with inheritance. You are using encapsulation. Since `SubName` is public you can access it anywhere. As such, your question doesn't make much sense. You'll want to edit it to clarify it.

Comment: You can access `Parentclass.Subclass.Subname` directly (if the subclass was created by the parentclass before use). But `Parentclass.Subname` is not possible.

Comment: Ok. maybe I used the wrong term here.
I just wanted to know if there is a way, I already thought that it is not possible, 
But just that i don't know it, doesn't mean that there is no way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to define the property to publish its properties directly?

No this is not possible as you would need multi inheritance to achieve this and Delphi does not support it. Either rework your class design or go through the hassle of implementing the needed properties.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi doesn't automatically recognise that.
But you can help it.

```
constructor TParentClass.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  fSubClass := TSubClass.Create(Self);
  fSubClass.SetSubComponent(True);
end;
```

like this you create a compound component
a component containing another component

changed from here:

```
unit uSubClass;

uses Classes;

type 
  TSubClass = class(TObject)
  private
    fProp: string;
  protected
    procedure SetProp(const aValue: string);
    function GetProp: string;
  public
    property Prop: string read GetProp write SetProp;
  end;

var SingleSubClass: TSubclass;

implmentation

procedure SetProp(const aValue: string);
begin
  fProp := aValue; 
end;

function GetProp: string;
begin
  Result := fProp;
end;

initialization
  SingleSubClass := TSubClass.Create;
finalization
  SingleSubClass.Free;
end;
```

that SingleSubClass is now a global variable and can be accessed in another object.

```
procedure TForm123.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(SingleSubClass.Prop);
end;
```

if you want other objects to be notified of a change on it, you'll have to add an observer pattern to it and register all interested objects for the changes
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/delphi

Comment: Yes indeed, but you can't access the properties directly in code then. This will only work in the designer, right?

Comment: you have 1 instance of TSubClass ?

Comment: And it's accessed by several other components ?
And you want to change the properties of that 1 instance via those other components ?

Comment: No i do not have components. Only classes and i want to access the property of the member Class directly in the "parent" class.

Comment: component or class ... what's in a name ?
What you need is path to a singleton instance of a class in certain unit
from within other instances of classes
i'll see if i can create a small sample code

Comment: That would only work if all ParentClasses that use this 'subclass' may have the exact same values in this subclass. If you set a property of the subclass in one parentclass, it will also be changed in all other parentclasses. Is that what you want ?

Comment: And in your code the subclass is not part of the parentclass either, which is what the OP wanted